# redraw one of the subview inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I have subviews inside a scrollview, and when user tap one of the subview, it would expand and show contents.

my question is it possible to just redraw the subview being tapped rather than layout all the subviews again. or whats the better approach to solve this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: why you not using UITableView instead of Scrolview..?

Comment: can you used the setNeedsDisplay method on the view that was tapped?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by saving a pointer to custom views in an array. So when user tapped on the subview, it resizes and delegate back to scrollview. The scroll view then redraw and change its content size with that array of custom views' height.

thanks for reading this post, and still welcome any suggestions!!